# Unknown bug when pressing the right/down arrow button

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

First of all **hello guys** :-]
I have a problem with my project - a game in the HTML5 Canvas.I will not tell you what you have to do, but i have unknown problem with my movement.

index.html{

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>StickySquares</title>
        <script src="scripts/main.js"></script>
        <style>
            #gameArea{
                background-image: url('images/bkg.jpg');
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body onload="init();">
        <div id="fastimages" hidden="hidden">
            <img id="bodyIMG" src="images/body.png" />
            <img id="wallIMG" src="images/wall.png" />
        </div>
        <canvas id="gameArea" width="640" height="480">
            ERROR... Update your browser!
        </canvas>
        <div id="debug"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

}

main.js{

```
var myCanvas, keyPressed = true;
var sprBody, sprWall;
var map = [];
var figures = [];
var debugtxt;
function unpressKey(){
    keyPressed = false;
}
function debugText(){
    debugtxt = document.getElementById("debug");
    var text = "";
    for(var y=0;y<15;y+=1){
        for(var x=0;x<20;x+=1){
            text += map[y][x].toString();
        }
        text += "<br />";
    }
    debugtxt.innerHTML = text;
}
function playerUpdate(button){
    // 37 - left, 38 - up, 39 - right, 40 - down
    if(!keyPressed){
        for(var y=0;y<15;y+=1){
            for(var x=0;x<20;x+=1){
                if(map[y][x]==2){
                    switch(button.keyCode){
                        case 37: // Left
                            if(map[y][x-1]==0){
                                map[y][x]=0;
                                map[y][x-1]=2;
                            }
                        break;
                        case 38: // Up
                            if(map[y-1][x]==0){
                                map[y][x]=0;
                                map[y-1][x]=2;
                            }
                        break;
                        case 39: // Right
                            if(map[y][x+1]==0){
                                map[y][x]=0;
                                map[y][x+1]=2;
                            }
                        break;
                        case 40: // Down
                            if(map[y+1][x]==0){
                                map[y][x]=0;
                                map[y+1][x]=2;
                            }
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    debugText();
}
function draw(){
    myCanvas.clearRect(0, 0, 640, 480);

    for(var y=0;y<15;y+=1){
        for(var x=0;x<20;x+=1){
            if(map[y][x]==1){
                myCanvas.drawImage(sprWall, x*32, y*32);
            }else{
                if(map[y][x]==2 || map[y][x]==3){
                    myCanvas.drawImage(sprBody, x*32, y*32);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
function init(){
    myCanvas = document.getElementById("gameArea").getContext("2d");
    sprBody = document.getElementById("bodyIMG");
    sprWall = document.getElementById("wallIMG");
    for(var firstIndex=0;firstIndex<15;firstIndex+=1){
        map[firstIndex] = [];
        figures[firstIndex] = [];
        for(var secondIndex=0;secondIndex<20;secondIndex+=1){
            map[firstIndex][secondIndex] = 0;
            figures[firstIndex][secondIndex] = [];
        }
    }
    for(var x=0;x<20;x+=1){
        map[0][x] = 1;
        map[14][x] = 1;
    }
    for(var y=0;y<15;y+=1){
        map[y][0] = 1;
        map[y][19] = 1;
    }
    map[2][2] = 3;
    map[7][9] = 2;

    window.addEventListener("keyup", playerUpdate, false);
    window.addEventListener("keydown", unpressKey, false);

    setInterval(draw, 1000 / 60);
}
```

}

When i'm testing my game and when i press the right and the down arrow key the square doesn't move with +1, it goes to the right wall or to the down wall...
I'm looking at my code but i can't understand why the square makes this mistake...
Can someone tell me what i'm doing wrong ? :)

**Edit** : I'm using 2d Array for the map:
1 = wall, 2 = block that can move, 0 = free space(where you can move), 3 - block that you can't move, but you can activate it when you are near.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its due to how you're handling key presses. Right now it can only accept one, it will override whatever the previous key is, that's why you can only go in one direction currently. This is how I prefer to do it.

```
var keys=[];

document.body.addEventListener("keydown", function (e) {
    keys[e.keyCode] = true;
});
document.body.addEventListener("keyup", function (e) {
    keys[e.keyCode] = false;
});

function updatePlayer(){
    if (keys[38]) {
       //up
    }

    if (keys[40]) {
       //down
    }

    if (keys[39]) {
       //right
    }

    if (keys[37]) {
       //left
    }
}
```

**[Live Example Demonstrating This](http://jsfiddle.net/dMYvG/)**

What this does is every time a key is pressed you set an element in the array with the same index number as they key code to true. When you stop pressing the key its set to false. Then you can just check where ever you normally handle player movement. This allows you to have pretty much an unlimited amount of keys pressed.

Comment: Thanks! Good example btw. :)